# Modeling longitudinal data with functional coefficients ignoring random effects

Tags: sas, longitudinal

I wonder if there is a way to model this following model in SAS (preferably with some built-in functions):

```
Y_{ij} = \beta_{i}(t_{j}) X_{i} + e_{ij},
```

which basically is a form of functional mixed-effects model without the random-effects parts. Here each subject `i` has observations at time `t_{j}` (`j=1`,...,`n_{i}`), and `X_{i}` is the covariates *not varying* with time within subjects but varying between subjects. The random errors follow iid normal distribution.

The closest form of model I found so far is the functional-coefficient model which normally is used for time-series data, although I'm not sure if it's applicable to time-invariant covariates. Anyone knows if there is a way to model this using some exiting software (preferrably SAS)?

Comment: You might want to tag SAS in this as well

Comment: Sound like Proc mixed or proc Hpmixed. See https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63033/HTML/default/viewer.htm#mixed_toc.htm